# Openning root terminal by keyboard shortcut

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, root, gnome-terminal

I am using Debian Linux and I am setting some shortcuts on it. So in keyboard window I went to shortcut, added `gnome-terminal`, and set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> as the keys.

But in Debian we also have "Root Terminal" so we can open a terminal session as root. I want to set a shortcut for this. What command I should allocate to it?

Comment: Just use `sudo`...

Comment: I don't want define sudo user...thank you

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Just type `su` in any terminal.

Comment: I know the usage of `su`. I think you couldn't understand me.... I wanted a shortcut for opening `gksu` commadn so that when I do `Ctrl+Shift+t` it also opens a root terminal again for me..See my answer that works and please test it to see what is happening..thank you for response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to **Keyboard** window and in the **Custom Shortcut** part the command is:

```
gksu gnome-terminal
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question has way too much unnecessary information, but I'll answer anyway.

Your best option is to open the menu in your menu editor(depends on what desktop enviroment you're using as to how you do it), when in the menu editor just mark the "Root Terminal" entry and figure out which command is used and then set that to your keyboard combo.

Comment: I didn't want to do that..I wanted to set shortcut for doing that. Please see the answer I found